# Query over the design of a multi-dimensional map of a structure that has its data hidden from some source code files in C

Tags: c, arrays, dictionary, structure, private

I'm developing a 2D tile map game where a tile is represented by a structure in an 'object' source code file. I want to represent the world map in a separate source doe code file by using a multi-dimensional array for the map.

However to hide the implementation details of the object it seems best to have the map source code not know anything about the details of the object structure (apart from requesting the size), and call specific functions in the object source code file to do any internal object processing.

Is this a better method than making the map source code include the object structure, or by manipulating the objects directly from the map code?

What do you think is the best way in C to deal with this design, and issues of keeping implementation details private for better code?

Thank you,
Richard

Answer (score 1):

Generally the best way to encapsulate code in C is to use functions instead of direct data structure access.

For example, lets consider a "person" data structure.  Instead of exposing this in your header:

```
typedef struct {
  int age;
  int weight_lbs;
} person;
```

Instead expose the following in your public header:

```
typedef void *person;

extern person person_create();
extern void person_destroy(person p);
extern int person_get_age(person p);
extern void person_set_age(person p, int age);
extern int person_get_weight(person p);
extern void person_set_weight(person p, int weight_lbs);
```

Then define the actual person struct in your .c or a private header.  The person_create() and person_destroy() are important since you must provide a way to create a person now that the underlying structure is hidden.

This offers the following benefits:

- Gives you the most control over how clients access your data
- Allows you to modify the data structure without breaking binary compatibility
- Allows you to use symbol versioning on the exposed functions

The main downsides are its more verbose and has a minimal performance penalty.  It can also be more difficult if you have more complex memory management concerns (want to use block pools, etc) but it can still be done.